# infinite loop scrolling using JavaScript doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I simply want to create infinitely moving object with javascript.
I integrate it with react just for exploration but the idea is to make it infinite

I have an issue that the result eventually is not quiet what I wanted to.
The issue is it goes correctly infinite to the left direction but not to the right, when moving to the right, **it only moves 2 iteration, and then no more objects appearing**

- **scroll** --> is smooth scrolling factor

---

**Here is the link to the code playground:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-loop-scrolling-c2iq0c

here is my code:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Physics from "./Physics";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";

export function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Boxes />
      <Physics />
    </>
  );
}

const totalbox = 16;

export const Boxes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {Array(totalbox)
        .fill(totalbox)
        .map((num, i) => (
          <BoxDetail key={i} keyindex={i} />
        ))}
    </>
  );
};

const BoxDetail = ({ keyindex }) => {
  const [{ pos: scroll }] = useStateValue();
  const boxRef = useRef();

  //infinite
  // total box * ( width + margin )
  const margin = 50;
  const width = 50;
  const WHOLEWIDTH = totalbox * (margin + width);

  function calcPos(_scroll, _position) {
    const temp =
      ((_scroll + _position + margin + width + WHOLEWIDTH) % WHOLEWIDTH) - margin - width;

    return temp;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const boxPos = 100 * keyindex;
    boxRef.current.style.left = `${calcPos(scroll, boxPos)}px`;
  }, [scroll, calcPos]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        ref={boxRef}
        style={{
          border: '1px solid red',
          position: 'absolute',
          color: 'blue',
          margin: '0px',
          width: '50px',
          height: '50px',
        }}
      >
        box {keyindex}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

the picture below shows -> going to right direction
[image: going to right direction]

the picture below shows -> going to left direction
[image: going to left direction]

Any idea where the problem is ?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to diagnose with a [mre]. You can use [Stack Snippets to create React examples](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552)

Comment: that would be great idea, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a more refined solution to infinite scrolling without any flickering behavior when either the boxes move to or move out the side of the screen

```
function calcPos(_position) {
    const temp =
      ((((_position - scroll) % WHOLEWIDTH) + WHOLEWIDTH) % WHOLEWIDTH) -
      margin;
    const isOffscreen = temp + width < 0 || temp > window.innerWidth;
    if (isOffscreen) {
      const distanceToScreenEdge =
        temp + width < 0 ? -temp - width : window.innerWidth - temp;
      const clampedPosition = Math.max(
        -width,
        Math.min(distanceToScreenEdge - width, temp)
      );
      return clampedPosition;
    }
    return temp;
  }

useEffect(() => {
  const boxPos = keyindex * (margin + width);
  boxRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${calcPos(boxPos)}px)`;
}, [scroll, calcPos]);
```

Comment: Very nice! Note that now that you have the `if (isOffScreen) {...}`, you no longer need to set `temp` in such a complex way. Instead of  `const temp = ((((_position - scroll) % WHOLEWIDTH) + WHOLEWIDTH) % WHOLEWIDTH) - margin;`, you could just say, `const temp =((_position - scroll + WHOLEWIDTH) % WHOLEWIDTH) -margin;`.

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem is in your method of wrapping around

You are using `% WHOLEWIDTH`, which is perfectly appropriate, for situations of scrolling one way. This is because, for example, if `WHOLEWIDTH` is 1500, then `1700 % WHOLEWIDTH` is 200, and `30050 % WHOLEWIDTH` is 50.

The problem is when you scroll in the other direction. `-300 % WHOLEWIDTH` will not automatically become 1200. You have a good mitigation, which is to add `WHOLEWIDTH`, before doing the `% WHOLEWIDTH`.

However that only deals with numbers in the range -1500 to 0. If the number goes more negative than -1500, the result will be negative, which is not what you want.

#### Solution

The simplest solution is to add not just one `WHOLEWIDTH`, but many. For example, try changing this line:

```
const temp =
  ((_scroll + _position + margin + width + WHOLEWIDTH) % WHOLEWIDTH) - margin - width;
```

to this:

```
const temp =
  ((_scroll + _position + margin + width + 10000*WHOLEWIDTH) % WHOLEWIDTH) - margin - width;
```

That will allow you to scroll the boxes to wrap round 10000 times in the negative direction and still have them all display.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, let me know if you have the ideal solution, I still don't have the solution to make the endless scrolling in both directions

Comment: There you go! Please mark as Accepted (green check mark) if it solves your problem